# array in java to process a sentence combined with strings and integers

Tags: java, arrays

I need to design a program in which the user puts the number of letter grades they received to calculate user's gpa. The thing is that the program needs the user to input "java gpa a 4 b 4 a 2 b -4," for example. I've only programmed in python, so I'm very new to java. I was thinking about using array to multiply each grade and eventually divided by the number of courses. Can java arrays differentiate strings and integers combined together though? I apologize if this question is confusing :/

Comment: No java arrays can have only one type. You could however make a custom object to encapsulate the information and make an array of those

Comment: You can have an array of strings `String[]`, and you can process each entry as an integer (if it can be parsed as one) or as just a string.  Of course if the information is expected to appear as pairs (which your example seems to imply), then you can take the items two at a time, and parse the second as an integer.

Comment: An array of `Object` can hold anything. Consider `Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a mix of strings and integers. I would also suggest not to use integers when GPA requires, either double or a float.

If you're set on using an array I would split the input and take only the grades you need into an array of doubles. With the size of the array being the number of grades they entered (index 0 is the first letter grade, index 1 is the second letter grade, etc).

When you are inserting them into the array you could convert the letter grade to their corresponding GPA points (hence why I suggest a double or float). For example, usually standard GPA system an A is 4.0 per credit, A- is 3.7 per credit, etc.

Once each is converted, loop through the array and perform the final calculations to get the overall GPA.

Hope that helps!

*Reference:*

**How to manually calculate your GPA:**

- Locate your grade on the grid.
- Multiply the Quality Points for that grade by the number of credits
  for the course.
- Do this for each course you took. Add all these products together.
- Divide this number by the total number of credits taken.

Comment: “GPA requires at least double precision”?  Why do you feel double precision is necessary?

Comment: I feel it is necessary because an A-  for example literally represents 3.7, not 4, not 3, 3.7. That .7 makes a difference. You can't store that in an int. (.7 will be cut off or rounded up to a 4).  Plus, if you have a lot of grades and you're cutting off the decimal then the function is not accurate and calculations will be completely off.

Comment: Single precision `float` variables would also work.  They have approximately 6.9 digits of precision, so can easily distinguish between 3.70000 and 3.70001; double precision variables have approximately 15.9 digits of precision, so can distinguish between 3.70000000000000 and 3.70000000000001 ... stating that the GPA calculation requires _at least this much precision_ is not defensible.  It isn’t wrong to do the calculations in double precision, but it is by no means required.

Comment: Yes, a float would work as well. I was merely pointing out that you need more precision than an integer can offer, not necessarily meaning it can **only** be a double.  I updated my answer to include a double or a float to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, it looks like you intend to run the command ...

```
java gpa a 4 b 4 a 2 b -4
```

... as in running java, with `gpa` as the main class, and passing it the arguments `"a"` `"4"` `"b"` `"4"` `"a"` `"2"` `"b"` `"-4"`.  These elements seem to appear in pairs ... a grade and then a number.  You could parse these value in pairs as follows:

```
class GPA {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i = 0;  i < args.length; i += 2) {
            String grade = args[i];
            int number = Integer.parseInt( args[i+1] );
            // ... Your additional processing here ...
        }
    }
}
```

The loop uses `i += 2` to increment the variable by 2 each time through the loops, so you examine `args[0]` and `args[1]` on the first pass, and `args[2]` and `args[3]` on the second, and so on.

`args.length` is used to determine how many arguments there are, so there is no need to make the last argument negative to detect this, if indeed this is what the `-4` was for.

Comment: Hi, this was super helpful, but just a question regarding increments of 2.. I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly :(

Comment: what exactly is it that don’t you understand?